# White wireframe box around objects

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When selecting an object in Gazebo, a white wireframe box is drawn on the screen.  Normally, this box outlines the object.  Sometimes it is in the wrong place (seemingly offset in a direction, or rotated to some incorrect axes).  What does this box represent? Is this bug isolated only to this visual display, or does it indicate something deeper?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3120/white-wireframe-box-around-objects/) by [mposa](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/381/mposa/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-06-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

The white box is suppose to show what model is selected, and it's also suppose to be the bounding box around the model. It's currently not working quite right. This is a known bug, but it doesn't affect the way Gazebo works.

Thanks for the feedback.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0